# gitlab bundle in backup files

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm in a terrible situation. I only have gitlab backup file of all repositories. Real repo is gone / corrupted.

I looked inside the archive and found repo.bundle file.

When I try to `git bundle verify repo.bundle` it says `"does not look like a v2 bundle file"`

Any suggestions? what can I do?

Comment: Would a clone of that bundle followed by a git gc work? (as in http://james.revillini.com/2010/01/17/solved-fatal-could-not-read-bundle-pathtoyourfile-ext-during-git-clone/)

Comment: @VonC tried, gc works only on .git files. I've a bundle...

Comment: Hence my suggestion to clone the bundle first (and do the gc inside the clone)

Comment: @VonC clonning fails with same error. or am I missing something?

Comment: http://james.revillini.com/2010/01/17/solved-fatal-could-not-read-bundle-pathtoyourfile-ext-during-git-clone/ does mention it display the same error message, but still recommend the git gc to get a functional repo.

Comment: @VonC he doesn't use gitlab, so it could be unrelated.

Comment: I agree. It was just meant as a test: would the clone work (even ignoring the error message) after a git gc in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here on the GitLab Forums](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/git-clone-on-bundle-file-from-gitlab-backups/1544/7), you could try to treating the .bundle file as a .tar file (which it actually is) and clone from the resulting bare repository. Hope that helps.